# How to autopopulate entity reference field w/ user-created entityform submission

Tags: rules, entities

I'm developing a website for recruitment for research associates. I am currently using [Entityforms](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) as the questionnaire.

I've created a rule to create an entity of a certain content type, which I call "associate applicant", which has a field for [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference). I want this field to populate with the entityform that the user submitted, upon submission.

However, right now you have to go in and edit the field and manually select the specific entityform (submission) in order to populate the field. Any advice on how to approach this problem and autopopulate that entity reference field with the user's submission?

I"m a beginner in Drupal development so any help is really appreciated! :)

Comment: This doesn't sound like it should be difficult. In your rules actions, either choose "set a data variable" if the field allows one value or "add an item to a list" if the field allows unlimited values. Then add the entityform submission.